# How can I use older versions of raspbian on RPi 2 B?

Tags: raspbian, compatibility, v4l2

By what I gather from various sources, I realize that the Rpi2 Model B does not support older versions of Raspbian. I wanted to make sure there is no work around for this.

I am trying to install the `2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.zip` version on my Rpi2 B because this is the only OS that supports stk1160 video grabber properly.

Is it possible to downgrade the kernel alone to 3.2.x on the latest Raspbian OS ?

Comment: Actually yes it is possible to use a new kernel with an old userland image, but if the issue is a hardware driver, which is what it sounds like, then the issue is actually the kernel.  This is a common scenario when manufacturers provide a proprietary driver -- they only compile it for one kernel and say, in not so many words, "Oh you have to use the kernel from 2013, we haven't bothered compiling a new one since then and we won't let anyone have the source code despite the fact you paid for the product".  Amazing but true.  I think it is so they can sell it as "linux compatible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The newer kernel is needed to support the armv7 processor and extra memory on the PI2.